# total internal reflection bugs in "ray tracing in one weekend"

Tags: c++, raytracing

I am following "Ray Tracing in One Weekend" to build a ray tracer on my own. Everything is OK until I met Dilectric Material.

The refraction performs well (I am not sure, we can see it in image 3 and 4), but when I add the total internal reflection, the sphere gets a black edge, the images are listed as below:

[img1 - black edge for total internal reflection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v80h5.png)

[img2 - black edge for total internal reflection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPp3X.png)

[img3 - dilectric without total internal reflection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvIDU.png)

[img4 - dilectric without total internal reflection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mMrw.png)

#### My analysis

I debuged my program and found that total internal reflection happens at the edge of the sphere, and the ray bounces infinitely inside the sphere until it exceeds boundce limits, so it returns `(0.f, 0.f, 0.f)` for the result color.
I don't think the infinite bounce of inner relection is right, but i have compared my code with the one in the book, and could not find any problem.

The `scatter` method is here:

```
bool Dilectric::scatter(const Ray& input, const HitRecord& rec, glm::vec3& attenuation, Ray& scatterRay) const
{
    glm::vec3 dir;
    if (rec.frontFace)
    {
        // ray is from air to inside surface, only refraction happens
        float ratio = 1.f / m_refractIndex;
        dir = GfxLib::refract(glm::normalize(input.direction()), rec.n, ratio);
    }
    else
    {
        // ray is from inside surface to air, need to think of total internal reflection
        float ratio = m_refractIndex;

        float cosTheta = std::fmin(glm::dot(-input.direction(), rec.n), 1.f);
        float sinTheta = std::sqrt(1.f - cosTheta * cosTheta);

        bool internalReflection = (ratio * sinTheta) > 1.f;

        if (internalReflection)
        {
            dir = GfxLib::reflect(glm::normalize(input.direction()), rec.n);
        }
        else
        {
            dir = GfxLib::refract(glm::normalize(input.direction()), rec.n, ratio);
        }
    }
    scatterRay.setOrigin(rec.pt);
    scatterRay.setDirection(dir);  
    // m_albedo is set to vec3(1.f)
    attenuation = m_albedo;
    return true;
}
```

outer method, `rayColor` is here:

```
glm::vec3 RrtTest::rayColor(const Ray& ray, const HittableList& objList, int reflectDepth)
{
    if (reflectDepth <= 0) return glm::vec3(0.f);

    HitRecord rec;
    // use 0.001 instead of 0.f to fix shadow acne
    if (objList.hit(ray, 0.001f, FLT_MAX, rec) && rec.hitInd >= 0)
    {
        Ray scatterRay;
        glm::vec3 attenu{ 1.f };

        std::shared_ptr<Matl> mat = objList.at(rec.hitInd)->getMatl();
        if (!mat->scatter(ray, rec, attenu, scatterRay))
            return glm::vec3(0.f);

        glm::vec3 retColor = rayColor(scatterRay, objList, --reflectDepth);
        return attenu * retColor;
    }
    else
    {
        glm::vec3 startColor{ 1.f }, endColor{ 0.5f, 0.7f, 1.f };
        float t = (ray.direction().y + 1.f) * 0.5f;
        return GfxLib::blend(startColor, endColor, t);
    }
}
```

`reflect` method is here:

```
glm::vec3 GfxLib::reflect(const glm::vec3& directionIn, const glm::vec3& n)
{
    float b = glm::dot(directionIn, n);
    glm::vec3 refDir = directionIn - 2 * b * n;
    return glm::normalize(refDir);
}
```

However, I am not sure my analysis is right or not, can any one lend me a hand and give me a solution for it? The main logic of the rendering is [here(including the total demo)](https://github.com/lyzirving/LightRender/blob/master/engine/rrt/RrtTest.cpp).
i will really appreciate your advice!

Comment: It surely shouldn't be pure black, because the incident ray to the observer (camera) will be a summation of refraction from inside the sphere (which can be zero due to total internal reflection) and reflection off the outer surface of the sphere.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for you comment! i will continue to read this book and find out what is wrong in my code.

Comment: @BenVoigt But i still wonder why the total internal reflection bounces infinitely.

Comment: Well in the real world, even though the absorbance of the glass may be quite low, it's non-zero and that is enough to make the intensity of light undergoing total internal reflection exponentially decay with distance.  As the intensity decays, it will reach a value small enough that quantum effects can no longer be ignored -- there will be a (random) point where the last photon is absorbed and reflection stops.

Comment: In your ideal material being simulated, if you have treated absorbance as exactly zero, then you would indeed get infinite bounces.